# InDesign CS3: Making the top layer more prominent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, typesetting

OK, I'm reasonably familiar with setting vertical type in Illustrator...but how does one adjust the letters left and right to properly align them? In a radio station call-letters (set vertically), one letter is noticeably to the right! Kerning does not do it...and (at least in CS3), I can find no "setting the baseline" function (or, seemingly, any other function to accomplish the task), so I'm stuck!!

I suppose I could "change the characters to art," then adjust the characters, but is this the only way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It would be very difficult to get a perfect result within a text box. In InDesign, you can try turning on Optical Margin Alignment (in the Story palette) and play with the settings. That works great for hanging punctuation, but would be a hit-or-miss proposition for a stack of caps.

I would convert each letter to an outline (start with a separate text box for each letter), then align visually. Depending on the typeface and specific letterforms, you may be able to make subtle adjustments to the width of one or two characters to improve the overall alignment -- keep it subtle, though, you don't want to butcher a nice typeface.